# __get как это работает?

Tags: php

Вот в файле я подключаю

```
include '/map.php';
include '/code.php';
include '/boot.php';
```

Как сделать чтобы файлы сами подключались когда потребуются?

В каком случае срабатывает _get()

---

Добавил пример

```
class vasek {

        private $classes = array(
                'config'     => 'Config',
                'request'    => 'Request'
        );

        private static $objects = array();

        public function __construct(){

        }

        public function __get($name) {

                if(isset(self::$objects[$name])){
                        return(self::$objects[$name]);
                }

                if(!array_key_exists($name, $this->classes)){
                        return null;
                }

                $class = $this->classes[$name];

                include_once('api/'.$class.'.php');

                self::$objects[$name] = new $class();

                return self::$objects[$name];
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неясно, от чего ты решил (и все поверили), что нужен маг. метод `__get`, когда речь идет о подключении файлов.

Нужен autoloader:

```
<?php

// или так:
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

// или так:
// function __autoload($class) {
//     include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
// }

?>
```

После добавления этого кода будет подключен нужный файл из директории "classes" при условии его правильного именования. К примеру, ты создаешь экземпляр класса `map`:

```
<?

$map = new map();
$map->some_method();

?>
```

Так вот, если к этому моменту объявления класса `map` не было, будет произведена попытка подключить файл "./classes/map.php" в надежде на то что в нем описан нужный класс.

Подробнее: [PHP OOP5 - autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php)

---

**UPD**

То есть, если ты хочешь, чтобы при обращении к `$vasek->map` получался объект класса `map`, нужно в массив `$classes` дописать свои классы. Странно, почему это сделано таким образом, но что есть, то есть. Я вот, к примеру, просто проверял наличие одноименного файла. Но тебе нужно вот что:

```
class vasek {

    private $classes = array(
        'config'     => 'Config',
        'request'    => 'Request',
        'map'        => 'Map',
    );

    ...
}
```

а потом — переместить файл "map.php" в "api/Map.php" (следи за регистром!).

Тогда при первом обращении к `$vasek->map` подключится файл "api/Map.php", создастся экземпляр класса: `new Map()` и сохранится в закрытом массиве `$objects` — чтоб при следующем обращении к этому св-ву тебе вернулся уже созданный ранее объект.

Comment: В Симпле cms не используется автолодер а файлы грузятся __get

Тем более на 5.1 работать это дело не будет

Comment: Откуда было знать, что речь о какой-то cms?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php
spl_autoload_register (PHP 5 >= 5.1.2)

Comment: Хм, я тут подумал и понял, о чем идет речь. Я как-то свой фреймворк писал (я Денис и я пишу на похапе уже N лет), так вот там такая штука была: основной объект-программа имел только необходимый надор методов и возможность расширять «модулями» — это происходило при попытке обратиться к свойству: если оно не определено, то в обработчике __get происходило создание объекта класса (одноименного с именем свойства) и назначалось имени этого свойства. Получалось, что при первом обращении к `$core->users` создавался объект и возвращался, при последующих — объект уже существовал.

Об этом речь?

Comment: (PHP 5 >= 5.1.2) - в этом вся проблема, у меня четко 5.1.0

сверху написал пример из симплы но я так и не понял как нужно извращаться чтобы он заработал

похоже только если наследуя все и вся от этого класса

Comment: Ну да, так и есть, как описано в моем комментарии выше: при обращении к свойству `$vasek->config` обработчик __get смотрит, есть ли в личном свойстве `$vasek->classes` это имя класса ("config"), и, если есть, подключает файл "./api/Config.php" с расчетом на то что в этом файле описан класс "Config".

Решение твоей проблемы, на сколько я ее понял, добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Эту магическую функцию нужно рассматривать вкупе с функцией такого же типа - __set().

В `__set()` и `__get()` описываются принципы создания и принципы получения неизвестного свойства (не описанного в классе) для какого-либо класса.

Так, например, можно неизвестые до какого-то момента свойства записывать в массив и оттуда же их вызывать при обращении к ним, после объявления.

Пример:

```
<?php
    class A {
        //свойство класса (в будущем - массив) для хранения не предопределенных переменных
        public $data;

        //определяем функцию хранения неизвестной классу переменной
        function __set($property, $value){
            $this->data[$property] = $value;
        }

        //определяем функцию извлечения добавленной ранее переменной
        function __get($property){
            return $this->data[$property];
        }
    }

    // тестируем работу магических функций

    //создаём объект класса
    $object = new A();

    //присваиваем значение новому свойству name
    $object->name = 'Значение свойства name'; // работает магический метод __set(), записывая значение в массив $data

    //выводим не предопределенное в классе свойство name
    echo $object->name; # сработает метод __get(), достаёт из массива date значение ячейки с ключём name, выведет - Значение свойства name
?>
```

Плюс можешь почитать [страницу](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php) в документации по этому поводу.